# Initializing objects in array of pointer to objects

Tags: c++, arrays, object

Having trouble initializing these custom (not STL) List objects with the following implementation. The Graph class contains an array of pointers to custom List objects. I'm pretty sure I went somewhere wrong with how I declared my lists array.

Snippet of header:

```
class Graph
{
    private:
        List **lists;
        int listCount;
    public:
        .......
        .......
}
```

Snippet of implementation:

```
//node integer is used for size of array
void Graph::setLists(int node)
{
    listCount = node;
    lists = new List[listCount];

    //for is used to initialized each List element in array
    //The constructor parameter is for List int variable
    for(int i = 0; i < listCount; i++)
        lists[i] = new List(i);
}
```

Errors I'm getting:

```
Graph.cpp: In member function ‘void Graph::setLists(int)’:
Graph.cpp:11:28: error: cannot convert ‘List*’ to ‘List**’ in assignment
```

Comment: What is `List` supposed to do and what is `Graph` supposed to do?

Answer (score 4):

The only problem I see is that you are trying to initialize `lists` with with an array of `List` objects instead of an array of pointers to `List` objects.

change

```
lists = new List[listCount];
```

to

```
lists = new List*[listCount];
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are creating an array of List objects, and not an array of List pointers.

```
lists = new List*[listCount];
```